# Why I can't see the “price” tab in itunes producer

Tags: app-store-connect, ibook, itunes-producer

I'm submiting my first book to the Ibook store.

Problem : In Itunes Producer, I can't see the "price" tab ? Do you know why ?[image]

Comment: I’m not familiar with iTunes producer, but with most apps, you can actually edit the toolbar. Try right-clicking it.

Comment: Nope... Weirdly, I see image like that on Internet http://selfpublisherbibel.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/itunesproducer3.jpg    and we can see the price tab on the top

Comment: Still just fishing around: when you created your iTunes connect account, did you make sure you created a *Paid* Books account and not a *Free* Books account?

Comment: You're right ! It was that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an account on [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/iBooksSignup) in order to distribute books, you can either create a **Free Books Account** or a **Paid Books Account**.

Apparently, for the **Price** tab to appear in **iTunes Producer**, you have to be logged in with a **Paid Books Account**. Make sure you followed the right procedure when you did create your account. If you didn’t, I’m quite sure you can somehow switch from *Free* to *Paid*. I don’t know how, though.